# How to acquire SPEC files from SRPM?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpm-spec

is it possible to specifically download only SPEC files (which are used in srpm files for rpm building) ?

Or more precisely, is there any server that would store only SRPM files available for download?

I've used fedpkg for downloading RPMs, then creating SRPMs out of them and thus acquiring the SPEC file - but downloading RPMs takes a lot of time, so I would rather want to download a SPEC file individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Fedora, you can find the sources on any of the official mirrors:  http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora/releases/29/Everything/source/tree/Packages/

You should also be able to use `dnf download --source $package_name` to download directly from your configured repositories.

Once the SRPM is downloaded, you can install it `rpm $package.src.rpm -ivh`, and the SPEC file would be at ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/$package_name.spec

If you do not want to install the SRPM and just want to extract the SPEC file, you should be able to run `rpm2cpio $package.src.rpm | cpio -idmv *.spec` and it will extract the SPEC file to your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go to the Fedora [git repository](https://src.fedoraproject.org/)?  For example, the link for the Firefox SPEC file is:

https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/firefox.git/plain/firefox.spec